# Controller unreliably receives value from page

Tags: visualforce

I have an odd situation with a relatively simple VF page. This page consists of a form with some conditional rendering of sections based on the user's response to the first question. I am trying to add validation to require a specific question (pp.Desired_Start_Semester__c).

About 1/3 of the time, the page works just fine and saves all values entered into the page back to the record as expected. The rest of the time, the field that I am trying to a require does not save back to the record. I've determined that this is because the controller is not receiving the value displayed on the page (i.e. a debug statement shows null immediately after the Save actionfunction is invoked).

After encountering this problem with the field, I switched to using two booleans bound to two inputCheckboxes (bolSummer18 and bolFall18). The problem persists with these completely new values!

My guess is that this error is somehow caused by the functions that hide/unhide sections of the page, but I don't understand why it would be intermittent!

Code is below:

**Page**

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" controller="volunteerScheduling_Controller" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="true" >

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <style>

        .btnDisabled{

            'background-color':'grey';
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        function setFocusOnLoad() {}
        $j = jQuery.noConflict();     

        function disableButtons() {

            var $buttons = jQuery('.buttonDisableonSave');
            $buttons.toggleClass('btnDisabled', true).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }

        function showSections() {

            var strInterested = $j('[id$=interested]').val();
            $j('[id$=saveButton]').attr('style', 'display:inline');
            if(strInterested == 'No_might_in_future') {

                $j('[id$=interested_reason_section]').attr('style', 'display:none');                
            } else {

                $j('[id$=interested_reason_section]').attr('style', 'display:inline');              
            }
        }    
    </script>

    <apex:outputPanel id="completeMessage">
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!bolFormComplete}">
            <apex:outputText value="FORM COMPLETE MESSAGE" />
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <apex:outputPanel id="introForm">   
        <apex:form rendered="{!!bolFormComplete}">
            <apex:pageMessages />         
            <apex:pageBlock title="Interested in volunteering this semester?">
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Are you interested in volunteering this semester?" for="interested"/>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!pp.Interested_in_volunteering_this_semester__c}" id="interested" required="true" onchange="showSections();"/>                    
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!lstStartTermOptions}" id="interested_term" required="false" >
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!SemesterOptions}" />
                        </apex:selectCheckboxes>                                                        
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>                                          
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel id="interested_reason_section" style="display:none;">
        <apex:form rendered="{!!bolFormComplete}">  
            <apex:pageBlock >
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Why are you no longer interested in tutoring?" for="interested_reason"/> 
                        <apex:selectRadio value="{!pp.Inactive_Reason__c}" id="interested_reason" required="true">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!inactiveReasonOptions}"/>
                        </apex:selectRadio>                                      
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>      
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>               
        </apex:form> 
    </apex:outputPanel>       
    <apex:outputPanel id="saveButton" style="display:none;">
        <apex:form rendered="{!!bolFormComplete}">
            <apex:commandButton value="Submit form" action="{!save}" reRender="introForm, completeMessage, interested_reason_section, saveButton"
                onclick="disableButtons();" styleClass="buttonDisableonSave" status="saveStatus"
            style="background:LightGrey;width:120px;height:45px;font-size:18px"/>
            <apex:actionStatus id="saveStatus" startText="Saving your responses..." />   
        </apex:form>          
    </apex:outputPanel>     
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
 public class volunteerScheduling_Controller {

    public boolean bolFormComplete {get;set;}
    public Program_Participant__c pp {get;set;}
    public list<string> lstStartTermOptions = new list<String>();


    public volunteerScheduling_Controller () {

        load();
    }

    public void load() {

        //do not re-process form, and show completed error message
        if(bolFormComplete == true) {

            return;
        }

        bolFormComplete = false;

        idPP = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('idPP');
        pp = [select id, Volunteer__r.Name,
                Interested_in_volunteering_this_semester__c,
                Desired_Start_Semester__c,
                Inactive_Reason__c
                from Program_Participant__c
                where id = :idPP];            

        //secure program participant data by clearing all displayed values in memory
        //note that this change is not committed
        pp.Interested_in_volunteering_this_semester__c = null;
        pp.Desired_Start_Semester__c = '';
        pp.Inactive_Reason__c = null;
    }        

    public list<String> getlstStartTermOptions() {

        return lstStartTermOptions;
    }

    public void setlstStartTermOptions(list<String> inStr) {

        this.lstStartTermOptions = inStr;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getSemesterOptions() {

        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('Summer 2018', 'Summer 2018'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Fall 2018', 'Fall 2018'));

        return options;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getInactiveReasonOptions() {

        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

        options.add(new SelectOption('Can\'t attend training(s)', 'Can\'t attend training(s)'));     
        options.add(new SelectOption('No longer interested', 'No longer interested')); 

        return options;
    }           

    public PageReference save() {   

        system.debug(lstStartTermOptions);

        if(pp.Interested_in_volunteering_this_semester__c
            == 'No_might_in_future') {

            pp.Volunteer_Status__c = 'Deferred';
        } else {
            pp.Volunteer_Status__c = 'Inactive';
        }

        pp.Desired_Start_Semester__c = String.join(lstStartTermOptions, ';');
        update pp;
        bolFormComplete = true;
        return null;       
    }
 }
```

Comment: 90% of the times I've seen this it ends up being a race condition, but I don't immediately see any of those standard issues here. Can you cut the code down to a minimal example that shows this behavior? It's a lot to wade through.

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed . I've cut down the example significantly and the issue persists. In fact, now, none of the values from the page are being passed to the controller, including pp. Interested_in_volunteering_this_semester__c which is bound directly to an inputField. 

I also went through and deleted all of my controller functions that were used to set booleans that controlled the visibility of sections. I instead replaced them with a jquery function to achieve the same effect

Comment: Is it possible that this is some weird caching issue in my browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your minimal code, you have three `<apex:form>` components, in the `outputPanel`s with ids `introForm`, `interested_reason_section`, and `saveButton`.

An [`<apex:form>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_form.htm#!) defines

> A section of a Visualforce page that allows users to enter input and then submit it with an `<apex:commandButton>` or `<apex:commandLink>`.

But two of your forms have no submission component at all (`introForm`, `interested_reason_section`) and the last has no data in its enclosing form for the `<apex:commandButton>` to submit. The components' native behaviors don't cross the boundaries of the form.

It's documented as best practice to use a single form at the top level of the page to avoid this kind of slicing and dicing of what elements get submitted to the controller when. If you need to control (re-)rendering of the form elements in a granular way like you do here, you can use nested `<apex:outputPanel>` elements:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="rerenderMe">
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{! myBooleanVar }">
        content goes here
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

That way you always have a target id rendered in the page for a `rerender` element to target (the outer, wrapping `<apex:outputPanel>`). You're already using this structure, just with inner forms instead of inner output panels.

Then, you wrap the whole page in a single `<apex:form>`, and don't connect the form element to any rerendering mechanics.